# Can't read string from file to structure c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple program that can read data from a file (inventory.txt) into a structure and then output that structure to the user. Every time I run the program, if the part of the file that would be a string (with spaces) has anything on it, the rest of the data gets omitted.
This is my code so far;

```
# include <fstream>
# include <iostream>
# include <string>
# include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct inven
{

    int part,quant;
    string descript;
    float price;
};

int main()
{
    cout << setprecision (2) << fixed;
    inven inventory[100];
    ifstream filein;
    ofstream fileout;
    filein.open ("inventory.txt");


    if (filein.good())
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                filein >> inventory[i].part;
                getline (filein, inventory[i].descript);
                filein >> inventory[i].quant;
                filein >> inventory[i].price;
            };
        }
    else
        {
            fileout.open ("inventory.txt", ios::trunc);
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {   
                cout << "Part Number: " << inventory[i].part << endl;
                cout << "Quantity: " << inventory[i].quant << endl;
                cout << "Description: " << inventory[i].descript << endl;
                cout << "Price per item: $" << inventory[i].price << endl;
                cout << "Total price: $" << inventory[i].quant * inventory[i].price << endl << endl << endl;
                if (inventory[i+1].part == 0)
                {
                    i=100;
                }
            }

return 0;
}
```

My text file currently looks like;

```
1
hammer
10
10
```

The above text file is really just a sample file, the finished product should be able to handle 100 different products.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you attach an output, too?

Comment: `Part Number: 1      Quantity: 0     Description:      Price:0      Total: 0`